# JOptionPane/If statement with increments

Tags: if-statement, joptionpane

Okay so I'm still fairly new to this and have a quick question. I have an assignment to write a program that calculates monthly bill. It ask the the customers package type (A, B, or C) and the number of hours that were used. It should display total charges. The kick is that each package has add on prices depending on the hours used.

Example:
Package A is 9.95 and month for 10 hours of access and additional hours are $2.00 and hour. I've got most of it figured out minus how to add the extra charges.

There are also two other packages that will be added. This is just the first bit. =)

This is my first time posting here, I apologize if my formatting sucks

Thanks for the help!

```
public class InternetServiceProvider {
public static void main(String args []){
    double packA = 9.95;
    double packB = 13.95;
    double packC = 19.95;

    String getPackage = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your package type:");
    String getHours = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many hours did you use?");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(getHours);

    if (getPackage.equals("a") && hours <=10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your monthly total is: $" + packA );
    }
    else {
        if (getPackage.equals("a") && hours > 10){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total is: $" + (hours + 2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're almost there for "a" (though you should post this on codereview.stackexchange.com and they'll help you out with doing it better). your only problem is that your math in the else is wrong. It's supposed to be "(packA + (hours - 10) * 2)"..... I mean... math is literally the only thing you got wrong.

Comment: No, do not post this on Code Review until it is working to the best of your knowledge.  Code Review only accepts working code, but will be glad to help you improve it once it is working to the best of your knowledge.

Comment: @Hosch250 I meant when he makes the math fix. Then it works.

Comment: Yes, that would be good.

Comment: Wow thanks! I was over thinking it I guess. Thanks you so much, that makes complete sense =P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the place for getting people to do your work for you... Anyway, here is what I would do (I am trying to do it in psuedo code):

```
package = price

get input for which package the user has

switch (package)
case a:
    if hours > 10
        hours = hours - 10
        final amount = hours * 2 + price of package
    else 
        final amount = price of package
    output final amount
case b:
    ...
case c:
    ...
```

Comment: That wasn't my intention. I was over thinking it and should have just stuck to the math. Thank you though!